# Safari 8 Yosemite multiple HTML5 video tags not playing

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-video

Managed to find a new bug in Safari 8 and wondering if anyone has a work around. Irritatingly it throws no errors but clearly is a problem because these examples work fine in Chrome and Safari 7 on Mavericks.

- http://hoverstat.es/clips
- http://neuemodern.com

On these two sites you will see the videos play fine on rollover in Chrome and Safari 7, however on Safari 8 only some of the videos play even though you can see the poster frame is replaced with the video data is remains static.

Comment: Are you looking for a workaround for a web page you're developing, or just a workaround to make Safari work generally? Because that's the difference between this being off-topic and being on-topic, and it's not clear.

Comment: A work around for a web page I'm developing. But the fact I've found other examples and it working on Safari 7/Chrome means it's not a problem unique to my implementation and a bug specific to this version of Safari. 2nd Example is my code.

Comment: I'm experimenting exactly the same situation right now. I have videos played on rollover, that was average but acceptable in Safari 7 but that became absolutely awful in Safari 8. Videos seem have trouble to keep himself loaded, it's like they are loading infinitely.
I've tried to play with Mime Type / re-export all my videos with new presets but I've still poor results.